# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing Delete method where from the user I get userId which I need to delete from the User table. But this user table is mapped to UserRole table through OneToMany mapping. So when I tried to delete the userId since userId is present as a foreign key in UserRole I cant delete that. Getting

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exam`.`user_role`, CONSTRAINT `FKj345gk1bovqvfame88rcx7yyx` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String profile;
    
    
    //user has many role
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
}

 @Entity
    public class UserRole {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long userRoleId;
        
        //User
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private User user;
        
        @ManyToOne
        private Role role;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First u need to delete the entry of that user from UserRole table then only it will allow you to remove from the user table because of the reference

Comment: Since we have cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true, it has to automatically remove the children table entry. We should not do it manually right ?

Comment: May be UserRole have one more reference with other entity?  I see Role  Entity is mapped in UserRole. try using target entity in the mapping

Answer (score -1):

First check if there is constraint , if so delete the related rows then you can delete.